# agGrid: Menu entry 'copy' in the context menu is missing

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I built a prototype grid with tree data in agluar and I was able to copy a cell range to clipboard via the context menu or the shortcut. Now I startet to implement the actual grid and I wasn't able to copy a cell range from the grid anymore. I tested different versions and discovered that the functionality is disabled with the change from release 21.x.x to 22.x.x. I also read about that ag grid disabled the paste functionality in the context menu, but it should be possible to paste values with the short cut. I tried to set the context menu items by myself but it doesn't works.

```
<ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      id="aggrid"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDefs"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      [animateRows]="true"

      [enableRangeSelection]="true"
      [suppressContextMenu]="false"
      [getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems"

      [treeData]="true"
      [getDataPath]="getDataPath"
      [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"

      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

```
  getContextMenuItems = function (params) {
    return ['autoSizeAll', 'expandAll', 'contractAll', 'resetColumns', 'export', 'copy'];
  }
```

Does anybody know how i can bring back the copy and paste functionality to my grid?

Thank you :)

Comment: can you add some more code or create a stackblitz?

Comment: This solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837146/ag-grid-angular-copy-menu-option-not-available